# How do I search for a value in a column and also get count of the column in a single SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, query-optimization

I have a table of following structure in MySQL 5.7:

```
CREATE TABLE `post_like` (
  `post_title_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_title_id`,`user_name`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and I have the following data

```
post_title_id    user_name

new-story        mani27
new-story        manipal
some-story       manipal
```

I am trying to get the count of likes for a particular story and also if a particular user has liked the story in a function `likeStatus(user_name, post_title_id)`

Suppose likeStatus(mani27, new-story) would result in:

```
count    status
2        1
```

I am using the following query right now and it works right:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_name) AS count,
COUNT(CASE WHEN `user_name` = ? THEN 1 ELSE null END) as status
FROM post_like WHERE post_title_id = ?
```

But this would execute the case function on all the rows in the table rather than searching the indexed column user_name.

I could use two different queries to get count and status of username liking a post, but  that would take much more time than this. So, is there an optimised way to get this output?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL is just the language.

Comment: @MBijen I am using MariaDB in my local environment, but it would be deployed in MySQL 5.7.17

Comment: Shorter:  `SUM(user_name = ?)`  But... Do you really want a value bigger than 1 for a "status"?

Comment: See also `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. I've changed SUM(user_name = ?) and nope I don't expect a bigger value as status but that's the best I could figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check the query but this should give you an idea. Try Group By

```
SELECT COUNT(user_name) AS count,
COUNT(CASE WHEN `user_name` = ? THEN 1 ELSE null END) as status
FROM post_like GROUP BY post_title_id HAVING post_title_id=?
```

> But this would execute the case function on all the rows in the table
>   rather than searching the indexed column user_name

When you group by basing on post_title_id= and then applying count functions on them, number of row searches for username can be reduced to rows in that group

Comment: Thanks @nikhil, I'm finally using
`SELECT COUNT(user_name) AS count,
SUM(user_name = ?) as status
FROM post_like GROUP BY post_title_id HAVING post_title_id=?`

Seems to be faster than two queries on a 1M records table

Answer (score 1):

Add your condition inside `CASE` not in `WHERE`, then make sure you use `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicates:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_name) AS count,
COUNT(CASE WHEN `user_name` = ? AND post_title_id = ? THEN 1 ELSE null END) as status
FROM post_like
```

Comment: In count, I would filter them with post_title_id or else I would receive likes for all posts combined. Hence, would this help?

`SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN post_title_id = ? THEN 1 ELSE null) AS count,
COUNT(CASE WHEN user_name = ? AND post_title_id = ? THEN 1 ELSE null END) as status
FROM post_like`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to scan all the records to see if a user liked the post. Just use a subquery on the select list. That should use the primary key index.
Something like this should work

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_like WHERE postid=? AND userid=?)
WHERE postid=?
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be same as executing two queries?